# Label style bold, italic same time

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (Convert.ToString( checkedListBox1.SelectedItem )== "Bold")           
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);           
}          
else if(Convert.ToString( checkedListBox1.SelectedItem )== "Italic")
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
}
else if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "UnderLine")
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: windows or asp.net which one you have doing

Comment: windows ,its working but when i change the selection index the fontstyle is changed i want the previous changed font remained stored . like in word we can make bold and italic of our font at same time .

Comment: bcz of if condition i can set only one value at one time. i want code like that if i change the selected value the previous value remains stored in it  unless i unselect it bcz in checkbox list we can select many values at same time .

Comment: where do you execute this condition? do you call it on checklistBox event ? or for example a button?

Comment: checklistbox  ! i want if two are checked it would be bold + italic and if i uncheck anyone of them then it will back to checked condition

Answer (score 3):

Pass `label1.Font.Style` every time and add your current style with it:

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "Bold")
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "Italic")
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "UnderLine")
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "Bold")
    {
        label1.Font.Bold = true;
    }
    else if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "Italic")
    {
        label1.Font.Italic = true;
    }
    else if (Convert.ToString(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem) == "UnderLine")
    {
        label1.Font.Underline = true;
    }
```

**Update:**
This works in Webapplication only.

Comment: 'System.Drawing.Font.Bold' cannot be assigned, it is read only

Comment: not working Error gives an error Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.Bold' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: my code is working but i want output like ms word if one value is selected other value will not change in if condition compiler always search a new value and delete the previous font style .

Comment: Sorry I was thinking its websolution.

Comment: i am using window application

Comment: if you can implement logic in asp I'll implement it in windows

Comment: The above logic works well in asp

Comment: I will give one more hint.  label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic); this will apply both bold and italic. You have to work around this.